# Can a polynomial with degree (r+s-1) have (r+s) distinct roots?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

While reading about generalised eigenvectors, i came to a strange proof. It goes like 
If p is a polynomial which has r distinct roots {λ1,λ2...,λr}, and q is a polynomial with s distinct roots {μ1,μ2...,μs}.
We can have two polynomials a(of degree s-1),b(of degree r-1) such that a(x)=p(x)^-1,when x={μ1,μ2...,μs} and b(x)=q(x)^-1,when x={λ1,λ2...,λr}.
Now a(x).p(x)+b(x).q(x)=1 for x={μ1,μ2...,μs,λ1,λ2...,λr}, all being distinct by definition. 
Writing ap+bq-1=0, has r+s roots, while its a polynomial with degree at most (r+s-1). How does it works? 
Reference http://math.mit.edu/~dav/generalized.pdf

Comment: It can, but then it will be $\equiv 0$

Comment: Your notation is difficult to read. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for formatting tips. I suspect that $ap+bq-1$ is the zero polynomial, which has a lot more than $r+s$ roots!

Comment: A polynomial of degree $n>0$ can have at most $n$ roots.  If $r+s-1=0$ is a possibility then you have the polynomial which is constantly $0$.  But that's the only case in which you have more zeroes than the degree.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown i still have to learn tex. Sorry to everyone who had difficulty in reading it. I will make sure i learn it at the earliest. Thanks!

Comment: Click on HELP. Go to the Help Center. Click on "How Do I Format Mathematics Here?. Read that and click on the next link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any nontrivial polynomial of degree at most $r+s-1$ can have at most $r+s-1$ distinct roots. So if $a(x)p(x) + b(x)q(x) - 1$ is equal to $0$ at $r+s$ points, that means it can only be the trivial polynomial which is $0$ everywhere.

Comment: I get it, all i had to prove is that if two polynomial(p,q) have no common irreducible polynomial, there exist two polynomial (a,b) such that pa+qb=1, much like the theorem for co-prime numbers. Thanks!